# Is there within and between R^2 for pooled cross section?

Tags: regression, panel-data, r-squared

I am writing a referee report for a paper that reports within and between $R^2$ for pooled cross-section regression that includes year fixed effects (but no panel or other fixed effects)so the regression has the following general form:

$$ y_{it}= \beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{it} + \gamma_t +e_{it}$$

Also the model uses this specification because one of the main variables of interest is time invariant.

I know that within and between $R^2$ does exist in panel regressions, such as fixed effects regression for example, but is it even possible to calculate separate within and between $R^2$ for pooled-cross section?

I know that for example for fixed effects panel regression the goodness of fit can be evaluated with respect to

$$\hat{y}_{it} = \hat{\alpha} + x_{it} \hat{\beta}$$

$$ \hat{\bar{y_i}} = \hat{\alpha} + \bar{x_{i} \hat{\beta}}$$

$$\hat{y}_{it} - \hat{\bar{y}}_{it} = (x_{it} - \bar{x}_i) \hat{\beta} $$

Where, we could get overall $R^2$ from model 1, between from model 2 and within from model 3. However, I can’t imagine a way how this could be applied to the model above.

I tried to research this issue, but any search on the within and between $R^2$ references some panel model other than pooled OLS. This makes me believe that this must be some mistake, but absence of evidence is not evidence of absence and I worry I overlooked something. Also I know that referee reports are anonymous but I still worry about what editor will think and that I missed or overlook something.

Comment: I hope you get a good answer on here, but you’re enough of an expert in your field that you’re being asked to review brand new research, and you don’t follow what the authors did. Others will be confused, too. Feel free to ask the authors what they did.

Comment: @Dave oh okay this is one of my first referee reports and it’s actually for conference with peer review not a journal - I am maybe overthinking it - I was surprised that I was even asked (probably because I submitted papers on similar topic there this time and also last time it was held) honestly I am pretty unsure what to do... I got some advice from people around and I am trying to do the best I can but I am bit overwhelmed by it - maybe I am overthinking it. I am bit scared to ask for clarifications from the author on account there might be some reason I should have known

Comment: “The authors should include a reference for how they calculated this quantity. I am aware of within and between R^2 but do not know it for pooled cross-section. Readers wanting to mimic or replicate this work should know the exact calculation.” Then you decide if you want to review the paper again once they’ve given a reference (major revision) or if you trust them to find a good one (minor revision). Certainly there could be other parts of the paper that could make you recommend a major revision or even a rejection.

Comment: @Dave thanks for the advice